# Fix two colours on UISlider swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift5, uislider

[Slider with two different colors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6ej8.png)

How can we make a slider with two fixed colors? The colors won't change even if the slider is moving. Also, the slider thumb should be able to side over any of those two colors. I should be able to define the length of the first section.

```
    func createSlider(slider:UISlider) {
    let frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: slider.bounds.width, height: 4)
    let tgl = CAGradientLayer()
    tgl.frame = frame
    tgl.colors = [UIColor.gray.cgColor,UIColor.red.cgColor]
    tgl.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.4, y:  1.0)
    tgl.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y:  1.0)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(tgl.frame.size, false, 0.0)
    tgl.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    
    let backgroundImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    slider.setMaximumTrackImage(backgroundImage?.resizableImage(withCapInsets:.zero),  for: .normal)
    slider.setMinimumTrackImage(backgroundImage?.resizableImage(withCapInsets:.zero),  for: .normal)
}
```

I have already tried this. But this dosent give me exactly what I wanted to achieve.

Comment: Hello and Welcome Xeb. - What have you tried so far? this seems like an interesting problem. If you can show your code so far and what isn't working, this would help people to help you.

Comment: Why do set a track image, if you just want a color? Have you tried `minimumTrackTintColor` / `maximumTrackTintColor`

Comment: Yes already tried that, it doesn't work for what exactly I want to achieve here. I want to make a slider with two fixed colors. The colors shouldn't change even if the slider is moving. Also, I should be able to define the length of the first section. See the image attached.

Comment: "I have already tried this. But this dosent give me exactly what I wanted to achieve." and what's the difference? What's wrong with your current code? Is your issue being with `backgroundImage` which is not expected?

Comment: see the image attached

Comment: There is no built-in solution for that. If you want static background images / colors that are independend from the current slider value, you need to do it on your own. Maybe this is inspiring: https://www.raywenderlich.com/7595-how-to-make-a-custom-control-tutorial-a-reusable-slider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one approach...

- set both min and max track images to "empty" images
- add left and right subviews to act as "fake" track images
- add a different color sublayer on each side subview
- when you slide the thumb, update the frames of the layers

Here's some example code... you may want to do some tweaks:

```
class XebSlider: UISlider {
    
    private var colors: [[UIColor]] = [
        [.black, .black],
        [.black, .black],
    ]

    // left and right views will become the "fake" track images
    private let leftView = UIView()
    private let rightView = UIView()
    
    // each view needs a layer to "change color"
    private let leftShape = CALayer()
    private let rightShape = CALayer()
    
    // constraints that will be updated
    private var lvWidth: NSLayoutConstraint!
    private var lvLeading: NSLayoutConstraint!
    private var rvTrailing: NSLayoutConstraint!
    
    // how wide the two "sides" should be
    private var leftPercent: CGFloat = 0
    private var rightPercent: CGFloat = 0

    // track our current width, so we don't repeat constraint updates
    //  unless our width has changed
    private var currentWidth: CGFloat = 0
    
    init(withLeftSidePercent leftWidth: CGFloat, leftColors: [UIColor], rightColors: [UIColor]) {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        commonInit()
        leftView.backgroundColor = leftColors[1]
        rightView.backgroundColor = rightColors[1]
        leftShape.backgroundColor = leftColors[0].cgColor
        rightShape.backgroundColor = rightColors[0].cgColor
        leftPercent = leftWidth
        rightPercent = 1.0 - leftPercent
    }
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() -> Void {
        // set both track images to "empty" images
        setMinimumTrackImage(UIImage(), for: [])
        setMaximumTrackImage(UIImage(), for: [])

        // add left and right subviews
        [leftView, rightView].forEach { v in
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            v.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0
            v.layer.masksToBounds = true
            v.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
            insertSubview(v, at: 0)
        }
        
        // add sublayers
        leftView.layer.addSublayer(leftShape)
        rightView.layer.addSublayer(rightShape)
        
        // create constraints whose .constant values will be modified in layoutSubviews()
        lvLeading = leftView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0)
        rvTrailing = rightView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0)
        lvWidth = leftView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0.0)
        
        // avoids auto-layout complaints when the frame changes (such as on device rotation)
        lvWidth.priority = UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 999)
        
        // set constraints for subviews
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            lvLeading,
            rvTrailing,
            lvWidth,
            
            leftView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            leftView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 8.0),
            
            rightView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftView.centerYAnchor),
            rightView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftView.heightAnchor),
            
            rightView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftView.trailingAnchor, constant: 1.0),
        ])
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        // we only want to do this if the bounds width has changed
        if bounds.width != currentWidth {
            let trackRect = self.trackRect(forBounds: bounds)
            lvLeading.constant = trackRect.origin.x
            rvTrailing.constant = -(bounds.width - (trackRect.origin.x + trackRect.width))
            lvWidth.constant = trackRect.width * leftPercent
        }

        // get percentage of thumb position
        //  based on min and max values
        let pctValue = (self.value - self.minimumValue) / (self.maximumValue - self.minimumValue)
    
        // calculate percentage of each side that needs to be "covered"
        //  by the different color layer
        let leftVal = max(0.0, min(CGFloat(pctValue) / leftPercent, 1.0))
        let rightVal = max(0.0, min((CGFloat(pctValue) - leftPercent) / rightPercent, 1.0))

        var rLeft = leftView.bounds
        var rRight = rightView.bounds
        
        rLeft.size.width = leftView.bounds.width * leftVal
        rRight.size.width = rightView.bounds.width * rightVal
        
        // disable default layer animations
        CATransaction.begin()
        CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)
        leftShape.frame = rLeft
        rightShape.frame = rRight
        CATransaction.commit()
    }
}
```

and a controller example showing its usage:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var slider: XebSlider!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let leftSideColors: [UIColor] = [
            #colorLiteral(red: 0.4796532989, green: 0.4797258377, blue: 0.4796373844, alpha: 1),
            #colorLiteral(red: 0.8382737041, green: 0.8332912326, blue: 0.8421040773, alpha: 1),
        ]
        let rightSideColors: [UIColor] = [
            #colorLiteral(red: 0.9009097219, green: 0.3499996662, blue: 0.4638580084, alpha: 1),
            #colorLiteral(red: 0.9591985345, green: 0.8522816896, blue: 0.8730568886, alpha: 1),
        ]
        let leftSideWidthPercent: CGFloat = 0.5

        slider = XebSlider(withLeftSidePercent: leftSideWidthPercent, leftColors: leftSideColors, rightColors: rightSideColors)
        
        view.addSubview(slider)
        slider.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        // respect safe area
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            // constrain slider 40-pts from Top / Leading / Trailing
            slider.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            slider.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -40.0),
            slider.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            
        ])
        
    }
    
    override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
        coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: { _ in
            // to get teh custom slider to update properly
            self.slider.setNeedsLayout()
        }, completion: {
            _ in
        })
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @DonMag. it totally worked for me... just one thing if I am giving the minimumValue and maximumValue to the slider the layer doesn't change the color.. can you explain how it's been calculated.

Comment: @Xeb - if you're setting min/max values for the slider, use the "value as a percentage of the range" like this: `let pctValue = (self.value - self.minimumValue) / (self.maximumValue - self.minimumValue)` ... then use `pctValue` instead of `self.value` in the next calculations. I edited the code in my answer to implement that.